# Storage (Session or persistent) in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web

I'm making a decision aid application for doctors treating cancer patient.
So my application contains a module that handles consultations presented in several forms that the doctor is needed to fill to get the decision generated by the application.
The thing is, The patient is needed to do multiple medical analysis and the forms must have the feature to be filled on multiple times.

I have a class called Consultation that have the full list of attributes that needed to be filled
but each form have only some of these attributes. The problem lays in the submission action.

To be more specific, the class have many constructors that enable the instantiation of an object with reduced number of attributes (I even don't know if that is the right approach)

My question is :

1. How can I save only portion of the data without actually make in them persistent(DataBase) knowing that the time between consultations can take weeks(I don't trust session to store data that long)?
2. If there is no way to implement the first question, how can I redirect only portion of the data to the database knowing that the consultation entity must have all the attributes filled or not?

I already tried sessions storage but I think it can produce security issues for the application moreover I don't trust a session to store data for a long time.
Passing to the database, I tried to set each form to a model but I didn't find a way to combine these model in one single table.
I still a beginner in spring boot but I have an overall understanding of the architecture.

Comment: Session storage seems to be a poor way to handle it.  Usually things like this are broken up into multiple tables in your database - i.e. a consultation has a one to many with an analysis.  And there may be specific types of analysis.  What does your DB look like?

Comment: My databse contains a tables with patient and a tables of consultation with relation of one to many but the analysis must be all set in the same table which is consultation all along with other attributes

Comment: While that sounds like a questionable DB design your only hope is that there are alot of nullable columns so that you can store a bit of the consultation at a time.

Comment: That's the approach, but if you have other advice I more than happy to accept it. I working on this application alone so I have to do pretty much everything. DB design is a major part specially in fetching data in next step so I open to every suggestion.